# amp-list from remote location?

Tags: google-amp, amp-list

I would like to use amp-list on a website that is otherwise valid AMP to avoid using an amp-iframe embed with JS. I just finished reading the cors docs by Google AMP at https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/amp-cors-requests and am still confused - **is it possible to have the json source for the amp-list from a remote domain**?

The thing I need is to have a source of URLs+titles generated and updated outside of the main jekyll website because the main website takes too long to build.

I am testing it with a valid JSON and headers as follows and am getting nothing in console and the list is not rendered, so I presume what I am trying to do is not possible?

```
/source.json
 Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
 X-Frame-Options: ALLOW
 Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token
 Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://fakename.netlify.com/
 AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin: https://fakename.netlify.com/
 Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
 Access-Control-Expose-Headers: AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin
```